Return 1 or 0 from PromQL query if the output out both PromQL result are same
I have two Prometheus metrics,
First PromQL
sum by (cluster) (
    cnp_pg_replication_slots_active{
       role="primary",
       cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"
    } == 1
)  

which gives me result like
{cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"}    2

Second PromQL
sum by (cluster) (
    cnp_collector_up { 
        role="replica",
        cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"
    }
)

which also gives me result like
{cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"}    2

Now I want to return 1 if both results are same or return 0 if any mismatch. how can I archive that?
If I write
sum by (cluster) (
    cnp_pg_replication_slots_active{
       role="primary",
       cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"
    } == 1
)  == sum by (cluster) (
    cnp_collector_up { 
        role="replica",
        cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"
    }
)

it gives me result as but I want result as boolean value 1 & 0.
{cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"}    2


In promQL you can use bool modifier after comparison operator to return 0 or 1 instead of filtering.
For example, metric > bool 100.
Demo for use in query can be seen here.
Documentation for this matter here.
Your query will be
sum by (cluster) (
    cnp_pg_replication_slots_active{
       role="primary",
       cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"
    } == 1
)  == bool sum by (cluster) (
    cnp_collector_up { 
        role="replica",
        cluster="p-vpt7bgc20z"
    }
)

